# Update a <div> when the user clicks on a <p> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have the HTML Code:

```
<div id=ytVid>
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5EdmHSTwmWY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/youtube.js"></script>
</div>
```

At the moment and I have a set of paragraphs that are generated by jQuery using an array.

What I would like to happen is that when the user clicks one of the generated paragraphs, this will start this code from the youtube.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function openLink(evt) {
        var search = evt.target.innerHTML;
        var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: yt_url,
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.data.items) {
                    $.each(response.data.items, function(i,data) {
                        var video_id=data.id;
                        var video_frame="<iframe width='420' height='236' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                        $("#ytVid").html(video_frame); 
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#ytVid").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I do not know if the above code is correct but what it should do is take what is in the array(if possible) or what is in the paragraph to search youtube for a video to update the ytVid div.

Thanks

Comment: clicking on a `<p>` item is not recommended. Try to use `<a>`. ( though I cannot see your `<p>` tag )

Comment: Ah ok then. [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/SamsJavaStuff/PADL9/) is my code. Its a simplified copy of the Javascript file but i dont know why it isnt working in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

In your "simplified" copy of the JavaScript jsfiddle, you have the strings wrapped in brackets, which signifies they are arrays.  You also didn't have jQuery selected to be included.

http://jsfiddle.net/PADL9/1/

And here's one with the JS from above added in

http://jsfiddle.net/PADL9/2/

(remove the alert/return for the AJAX to work)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Its a great reply! I have added this code in and the alert works. Once I remove them though it doesnt update the youtube video...